# How to address an assembly's dependency in C# when using Assembly.loadfrom()

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have created a C++ wrapper class library to import a C++ native dll. And I have added a project reference of this C++ class library to my C# application and copied all the dependencies to the Debug folder. So far every thing is working  fine unless I want to do the same process for a an older version of that C++ native dll. Obviously I can't have two dll(s) with same name and also same name for the dependencies in a folder. So I decided to have a c# assembly wrapper for each version of c++ wrapper and have each assembly dll and it's dependencies in a separated folder.

Given that I can't use project reference any more because it needs the reference dll to be copied in a  same folder of executable app, I tried to use **Assembly.LoadFrom()** to load the wrapper assembly on run-time and it loads the assembly but when it reaches to the Invkode line:

```
bject[] p = new object[] { command, null,format,handle};
uint ret= (uint) mi.Invoke(obj,p)
```

It throws an exception saying:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MDVRCLib, Version=1.0.6110.25310, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Once again if I use this assembly as a project reference and copy all it's dependencies to the project folder it will work fine. I am wondering while I am using Assembly.LoadFrom() to load the assembly from a different folder, how can I address the assembly's dependencies too, to prevent such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach to *static* `AssemblyResolve` event

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) =>
{
    //determine the required assembly using "e.Name"
    var filename = "....."; 
    return Assembly.LoadFile(filename)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides AssemblyResolve event, the 'probing' element could be used in application configuration file like this:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The privatePath holds the folders (relative to the executable) where the assemblies are to be searched.